# Extend existing Gradle task and override configuration

Tags: gradle, dropwizard

I'd like to define a new task called `dbStatus` that calls (or extends?) `run`, and just overrides the `args` property.

```
apply plugin: 'application'

run {
    args "server", "service.yml"
}


task(dbStatus, type: run) {
    args "db", "status", "service.yml
}
```

This doesn't work because `"run"` isn't a valid task class.  Is there a quick way to extend a task and just override a property?

#### UPDATE: Resolution

Unfortunately I had to just define a brand new `JavaExec` task, and recreate the logic that `run` is configured to do.  Here is what I came up with:

```
task(dbStatus, type: JavaExec) {
    main mainClassName
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args "db", "status", "service.yml"
}
```

I don't think this is exactly the same as `run`, since it isn't running against the build `jar` I don't believe, but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tasks cannot be "extended" in this way. Instead, declare another task and configure it as appropriate. (It's common to configure multiple tasks at once to avoid code duplication.)

Comment: So the existing `run` task looks to be a `JavaExec` task type (provided by the `application` plugin), so I would just need to recreate the logic it is doing?

Comment: You need to declare another task of type `JavaExec` and configure it as appropriate (at least `main` and `args`). See `JavaExec` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Updated question with my resolution.  If you see anything that could be better, please let me know.  I'd prefer to have `dependsOn: shadowJar` and somehow run the `java -jar` command against the built jar, but I'm just not familiar enough with gradle to understand how to retrieve all the variables that the different tasks are using (e.g. reference to built jar, build dir, etc).  Thanks for your help

Comment: Your `dbStatus` configuration above is exactly how `run` is preconfigured by the `application` plugin. If `shadowJar` is of type `Jar`, you can change `classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` to `classpath shadowJar` (which is short for `classpath shadowJar.outputs.files`). This will also add an inferred task dependency, so you don't need an explicit one. Currently, `JavaExec` needs an explicit main class name; there is no equivalent to `java -jar`.